# Способы распределение a различных бананов, b различных яблок и c различных груш - C++

Tags: c++, комбинаторика

Влад хочет взять с собой для ланча пару фруктов. У него есть `a` различных бананов, `b` различных яблок и `c` различных груш. Сколькими способами он может выбрать 2 разных фрукта из имеющихся у него?

Входные данные:
В одной строке заданы три неотрицательных числа: `a`, `b`, `c`. Все числа не превышают 10<sup>6</sup>.

Выходные данные:
Вывести количество способов, которыми можно выбрать 2 фрукта разного вида.

Мой код показывает всего 85%. Подскажите, в чем ошибка? Все идеи перепробовал.
Ссылка на задачу: https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/contests/9746/problems/85771

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    int a, b, c,res;
    scanf("%d %d %d" ,&a,&b,&c);
    res = a*b + a*c + c*b;
    printf("%d",res);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну подумайте немного - если у вас до 10<sup>6</sup> значения переменных, то произведения какие будут? до 10<sup>12</sup>. А максимальный `int` какой?

Замените `int` на `long long` - с соответствующей заменой спецификаторов формата - и у вас все получится.

Но раз уж C++, я бы делал так:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    long long a, b, c;
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    cout << a*b + a*c + c*b << endl;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, не подумал об этом.

Comment: давать готовый код к текущей олимпиаде несколько не спортивно...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Ну, так то оно так... но у человека ведь все полностью решено - тип только не тот. А вот подсказать, как лучше - мне кажется, ничего страшного.

Comment: @Harry, не имею ничего против подсказки про размер типа, но вот готовый код для примера iostreams ИМХО излишний...