# задача на С++ "обед"

Tags: c++

Задача - 
Влад хочет взять с собой для ланча пару фруктов. У него есть a различных бананов, b различных яблок и c различных груш. Сколькими способами он может выбрать 2 разных фрукта из имеющихся у него?

Входные данные
В одной строке заданы три неотрицательных числа: a, b, c. Все числа не превышают 10<sup>6</sup>.

Входные данные
Вывести количество способов, которыми можно выбрать 2 фрукта разного вида.

Код

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a,b,c;
    cin >>a>>b>>c;
    int n=a*b+a*c+b*c;
    cout<<n;
}
```

На e-olymp даёт только 85%, что не так с кодом?

Comment: `if(n<0)n=-n;` - это что за фигня?

Comment: В задачах на вероятность (и не только) используются специальные слова, которые надо научиться узнавать и расшифровывать. Здесь **различные** бананы означают, что выбор двух разных бананов - это разные события. Вывод: за такие формулировки задач надо убивать на месте.

Comment: преобразования числа в положительное если оно отрицательное, если это неправильно то я к сделать правильно?

Comment: Как вы получаете отрицательные числа из неотрицательного дано? Да и откуда в комбинаторике и яблоках отрицательные числа?

Comment: @Dmig это для случаев, когда *некто* отбирает яблоки у Влада

Comment: я уже понял, но как сделать тогда правильно если так тоже 85%?

Comment: Может из-за использования int вместо `unsigned char` и `unsigned short` для `n`? А может вообще из-за переменной `n`

Comment: Для перехода по ссылке нужна регистрация или вход. Верните условие без ссылки

Comment: Дубликат: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/789730/262953](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/789730/262953)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Основы комбинаторики 
 
Вам нужна функция вычисляющая факториал от числа 
Потом нужно выбрать одну из формул, которая подходит к условию задачи
И просто прописать ответ в виде формулы:

Ресурсы где можно найти, разобрать и понять их: 
https://www.matburo.ru/tv_komb.php 
http://old.nsu.ru/mmf/tvims/chernova/tv/lec/node3.html

Можно было дать и готовый код. Но вам в первую очередь нужно самому понять суть задачи

Answer (score 4):

Давайте прикинем. Значения в условии - до 10<sup>6</sup>. Значит, ваши произведения будут иметь значения до 10<sup>12</sup>.

Напомните, какое максимальное значение можно хранить в переменной типа `int`?

Дальше намекать?...